# With C# / Winforms / GDI+, how do i do getpixel or getimage of a control?

Tags: winforms, gdi+

I want to 'grab' the image of a control on my winforms dialog. I can access the 'graphics' context for the control using:

```
MyControl.CreateGraphics()
```

But how do i copy a rectangle from that graphics context to an image, or a bitmap, or call getpixel on it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've had some hackish success using MyControl.DrawToBitmap, is that a good way to go? Or is there a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think MyControl.DrawToBitmap is the way to go:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(MyControl.Width, MyControl.Height);
MyControl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, MyControl.ClientRectangle);
```

If you need to get the pixels then use Bitmap.GetPixel or Bitmap.LockBits